# How do I select the latest rows for all users?

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table similar to the following:

```
=> \d table
                                      Table "public.table"
   Column    |            Type             |            Modifiers
-------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------------
 id          | integer                     | not null default nextval( ...
 user        | bigint                      | not null
 timestamp   | timestamp without time zone | not null
 field1      | double precision            |
```

As you can see, it contains many `field1` values over time for all users. Is there a way to efficiently get the latest `field1` value for all users in one query (i.e. one row per user)? I'm thinking I might have to use some combination of `group by` and `select first`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest with `DISTINCT ON` in Postgres:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (id)
       id, timestamp, field1
FROM   tbl
ORDER  BY id, timestamp DESC;
```

More details:

- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/49540/how-do-i-efficiently-get-the-most-recent-corresponding-row/49555#49555
- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Aside: Don't use `timestamp` as column name. It's a [reserved word](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html) in SQL and a basic type name in Postgres.